# push Notification, php error and warnings

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I know there are many questions for this but I have tried doing all the suggestions with no luck, I have the below error when running my push.php in shell command., I am following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)  and everything worked untill the php. i recreated the certificates and keys many many times and since it's letting me connect using openssh then i guess the problem is not with it. today i have again recreated all the certificates and did a new project now I don't even receive the first prompt of do you accept to allow push notification  in this app. I am stuck I am on a deadline and was facing this problem for week, please help me, my php is exact same file as the tutorial with modified token and passcode I have added the path to ck.pem as was suggested by some of the S.O.answers but not working yet.also I have added CA file entrust_2048_ca.cer , it didn't help resolving the issue. and all this is using development certificate and not yet on a server, what might be the issues your ideas? is using external library will be better ?
Thank you for your help in advance.

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file
>   `/Users/.../..../.../.../ck.pem' in
>   /Users/dalyaseen/Documents/test3d/test3d/push.php on line 19
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): failed to create an SSL handle in
>   /.../..../.../.../push.php on line 19
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in
>   /Users/.../..../.../.../push.php on line 19
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in
>   /Users/.../..../.../.../push.php on line 19 Failed to connect: 0

here is the php script

```
<?php
#$deviceToken='ac49c9c8 a7d7f340 1c5c9af8 b8afeada ee7cdb77 051f12e8 90c314e1 129af45e';
$deviceToken='ac49c9c8a7d7f3401c5c9af8b8afeadaee7cdb77051f12e890c314e11y8u89i9o0lp';
# Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '1234';

# Put your alert message here:
$message = 'push msg!';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/Users/d/Documents/test/test/ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', '/Users/d/Documents/test/test/entrust_2048_ca.cer');
#stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', 1);
#stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', 1);

 //Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: Some google search gives me this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013848/sending-ios-notification-through-a-php-script-unable-to-set-private-key-file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762803/apn-error-in-server-script

Comment: can u put it some code from you php  script, and also in the mentioned tutorial you will get a simplepush.php file, try replacing your device token in it and run the script, if you receive a nori. then all your certificate are proper and its only a server issue, if not, then u probably messed up the certificates and keys..

Comment: Also see [“verify error:num=20” when connecting to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23351633/608639). You should ensure three things: (1) TLS 1.0 or above; (2) Server Nam Indication; (3) *Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)* root.

Answer (score 5):

Try This Code :

```
<?php

$deviceToken='ac49c9c8a7d7f3401c5c9af8b8afeadaee7cdb77051f12e890c314e11y8u89i9o0lp';
$passphrase = '1234';
$message = 'push msg!';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
$fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

//echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
);


// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    return 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
?>
```

**IMP**: Put your ck.pem file parallel to this code.
Once your code works you can change the position of your .pem file.

**Make Sure** the certificate you created is in "Developer" Mode
**Also**, the device is added to the provisioning profile.